# When do you receive the GVSP status code 0x800C : The requested packet is not available anymore?

Tags: c++

I'm using a GigE camera.
I can receive packets from the camera.
But, when I choose the larger width and height, I receive the GVSP status code 0x800C.
It tells me that the requested packet is not available anymore.
How can I fix it? Why do I receive this error message?

Comment: What does the [documentation](https://www.ab-soft.com/HLP/ActiveGige.pdf) say about it?

Comment: I may have used the wrong tag. I read this [documentation](https://www.visiononline.org/userAssets/aiaUploads/File/GigE_Vision_Specification_2-0-03.pdf).

Comment: Your documentation is more correct. My google-fu of `GigE SDK` pulled up basically a wrapper library around the `GigE Vision` library.